# How to replace a String of text from a text file with an ArrayList from user input

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a text file “test.txt” in which I store student details such as I.D number and course taken.
I want new students to be added immediately before the line that with “LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINE”.
The problem I have is that I’m collecting the student details in an array list called “objectInputFieldsList”. I’ve been trying to replace “LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINE” with “objectInputFieldsList” + “LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINE”.
The problem is that the two don’t mix – one is an array list and the other a string. The array list contains input from text field values from users.
How can I approach this successfully and replace LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINE  with “objectInputFieldsList” + “LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINE” ?
Thank you all so much in advance.

Here’s what I’ve been trying so far:

Sample text file before update:

```
123 | Oliver | Muchai
456 | Revilo | Chamu
LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENNAMES

Classes | 123 | English
Classes | 456 | Bilogy
LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENSUBJECTS
```

After an update with a new user the text file should look as:

```
123 | Oliver | Muchai
456 | Revilo | Chamu
678 | Eddys | Rockery
LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENNAMES

Classes | 123 | English
Classes | 456 | Biology
Classes | 678 | Kiswahili
LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENSUBJECTS
```

The Code:

```
        // The ArrayList called from the class that gets the user input from the JTextFields
        AddNewClientSaveAction save = new AddNewClientSaveAction();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();


        String lastNames = "LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENNAMES ";
        String lastSubject = "LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENSUBJECTS";

        String textToEdit1 = lastNames;
        int cnt1 = sb.indexOf(textToEdit1);
        String replacementString1 = "\n" + save + "\n" + lastNames;
        sb.replace(cnt1,cnt1+textToEdit1.length(), replacementString1);
```

Comment: What's `sb` in your code? And can you post `sb.replace(....)` method!

Comment: @Azad My guess is `StringBuilder`....

Comment: Sorry about that: StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

Comment: Get the index of the where `LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENNAMES`, use `StringBuilder#insert` to insert BEFORE this index point...If you don't want to keep the `LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENNAMES`, find it's index again and use `StringBuilder.delete` to remove the text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not a complete or full solution, but an example of a concept**

This assumes that you are reading all the text from the to start with...life would substantially more difficult if you're not.

This basically uses `StringBuilder#indexOf` to find the index point where are particular `String` literal exists.  In this example, we're only looking for `LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENNAMES`, but should get the idea...

From there, for each new record line, we create a temporary `String` to be inserted and then insert this before the previous obtained index point....

Now.  It wouldn't be a difficult thing to add in the subjects as well...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileUpdate {

    public static final String LAST_STUDENT_LINE = "LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENNAMES";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
        List<Student> objectInputFieldsList = new ArrayList<>(25);
        objectInputFieldsList.add(new Student(128, "Banana", "Pajamas"));

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
            String text = null;
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
                sb.append(text);
            }

            System.out.println("Before");
            System.out.println(sb);

            for (Student s : objectInputFieldsList) {

                int insertIndex = sb.indexOf(LAST_STUDENT_LINE);
                StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(128);
                line.append(s.getId()).append(" | ").append(s.getFirstName()).append(" | ").append(s.getLastName()).append("\n");
                sb.insert(insertIndex, line.toString());

                // Find subject mark and add the students subjects in as well...

            }

            System.out.println("\nAfter");
            System.out.println(sb);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException exp) {
            }
        }

    }

    public static class Student {

        private int id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }            
    }
}
```

This outputs...

```
Before
123 | Oliver | Muchai
456 | Revilo | Chamu
LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENNAMES

Classes | 123 | English
Classes | 456 | Bilogy
LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENSUBJECTS

After
123 | Oliver | Muchai
456 | Revilo | Chamu
128 | Banana | Pajamas
LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENNAMES

Classes | 123 | English
Classes | 456 | Bilogy
LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINENSUBJECTS
```

Now...Having done all that...

I'd recommend using a single user database, something like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) for example, or even XML, which would have to be significantly easier and lot less messy in the long wrong - IMHO

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I think you got the part about the example text file wrong. The two parts show the before and after of the same text file.

Comment: There is an additional line `128 | Banana | Pajamas`, it starts with 2 ends with 3 lines of students.  I just didn't bother to add the classes, can't do everything for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a Java `ArrayList`, you can use the `ArrayList#add(int index, E element)` method to insert an element at a specified position in the list.

Use as `index` the index before the element that contains your end of line "lastName".

This solution in case you want to add the string inside the `ArrayList`.

Comment: what is AddNewClientSaveAction ?

Comment: This is a class that collects user input from JTextFields and puts them into an ArrayList for storage in a text file by the above code (I've excluded some other parts of the class where the above code exists)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want to write new Student into your "test.txt" before "LATSTUDENTTEENTRYLINE".

First put your whole txt into a StringBuffer, because than your able to write at a special index.

Use

```
sb.getIndexOf("LASTSTUDENTEENTRYLINE");
```

and get the size of your string you want to add

```
String line = "Student | foo | bar";
int index = line.length();
```

now you have to write the line at

```
sb.getIndexOf("LASTSTUDENTTEENTRYLINE") - index;
```

in your StringBuffer.
At the end you write the whole StringBuffer to the txt.
Maybe you have to put at your line

```
+ "\n"
```

to make a new line so it looks better in the txt